# Как вывести определённые блоки при выборе checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет! Как можно вывести определённые блоки при выборе определённого checkbox? 
Нужно что бы при выборе определенной рубрики, остальные скрывались. 
 Например при выборе рубрики "Общие события" показывались только события имеющие data-rubric="1"

```js
$('.filter-rubric__item').change(function() {

});
```

```css
.filter-rubric__list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 12px;
}
.filter-rubric__label span {
  display: none;
}
.filter-rubric input {
  display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}
.filter-rubric__label {
  color: #979797;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  padding: 9px 0 14px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.filter-rubric__item:first-child .filter-rubric__label {
  padding: 3px 0 14px 0;
}
filter-rubric__label:before {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 9px;
  width: 16px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .filter-rubric__label span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1px;
  top: 10px;
}
.filter-rubric__label span > svg {
  height: 15px;
  width: 16px;
  fill: #ff5711;
}
svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.timeWidth {
  width: 178px;
}
.time-message__event-info--purple {
  background-color: #eee5f4;
}
.time-message__event-info {
  min-height: 101px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
.timeWidth {
  width: 178px;
}
.timeLeft__360min {
  left: 360px;
}
.timeLeft {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
.time-message__event-info--blue {
  background-color: #a9dcf6;
}
.time-message__event-info {
  min-height: 101px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
.time-message__event-info--pink {
  background-color: #fed5d5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-menu filter-rubric">
  <ul class="filter-rubric__list">
    <li class="filter-rubric__item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="1" id="rubric-1">
      <label for="rubric-1" class="filter-rubric__label">Наука<span><!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 16 15" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16 15;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<path d="M4.4,7l2.2,4c0,0,3.5-8.2,9.1-11C15.6,2,15,3.7,16,5.7c-2.4,0.5-7.5,6.4-9.1,9.3c-2.3-2.7-5-4.8-6.9-5.5L4.4,7z
 "></path>
</svg>
</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="filter-rubric__item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="2" id="rubric-2">
      <label for="rubric-2" class="filter-rubric__label">Спорт<span><!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 16 15" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16 15;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<path d="M4.4,7l2.2,4c0,0,3.5-8.2,9.1-11C15.6,2,15,3.7,16,5.7c-2.4,0.5-7.5,6.4-9.1,9.3c-2.3-2.7-5-4.8-6.9-5.5L4.4,7z
 "></path>
</svg>
</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="filter-rubric__item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="3" id="rubric-3">
      <label for="rubric-3" class="filter-rubric__label">Искусство<span><!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 16 15" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16 15;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<path d="M4.4,7l2.2,4c0,0,3.5-8.2,9.1-11C15.6,2,15,3.7,16,5.7c-2.4,0.5-7.5,6.4-9.1,9.3c-2.3-2.7-5-4.8-6.9-5.5L4.4,7z
 "></path>
</svg>
</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="filter-rubric__item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="4" id="rubric-4">
      <label for="rubric-4" class="filter-rubric__label">Общие события<span><!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 16 15" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16 15;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<path d="M4.4,7l2.2,4c0,0,3.5-8.2,9.1-11C15.6,2,15,3.7,16,5.7c-2.4,0.5-7.5,6.4-9.1,9.3c-2.3-2.7-5-4.8-6.9-5.5L4.4,7z
 "></path>
</svg>
</span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div data-rubric="1" class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--purple timeWidth">
  <div class="time-message__info">
    <p class="time-message__duration">07.00 - 08.00</p>
    <p class="time-message__name">Подъём и зарядка</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-rubric="2" class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--blue timeLeft timeLeft__360min timeWidth">
  <div class="time-message__info">
    <p class="time-message__duration">09.00 - 10.00</p>
    <p class="time-message__name">Математика и геометрия</p>
    <p class="time-message__description">Смена "Смена кубок", группа А.</p>
    <p class="time-message__location">(ауд.Менделеева)</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-rubric="3" class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--pink timeLeft timeLeft__360min timeWidth timeWidth__180min">
  <div class="time-message__info">
    <p class="time-message__duration">09.00 - 12.00</p>
    <p class="time-message__name">Мастер-класс Павла Бурре</p>
    <p class="time-message__description">Смена "Спортивной надежды сборной",</p>
    <p class="time-message__location">(стадион "Шайба")</p>
  </div>
  <div class="js-close-subevent time-message__event-in" style="display: none;">
    <div class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--darkpink timeWidth timeWidth__30min">
      <div class="time-message__info">
        <p class="time-message__duration time-message__duration--sub">09.00 - 09.30</p>
        <p class="time-message__name time-message__name--sub">Сбор - выход</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--darkpink timeLeft timeLeft__30min-sub timeWidth timeWidth__90min">
      <div class="time-message__info">
        <p class="time-message__duration time-message__duration--sub">10.00 -11.30</p>
        <p class="time-message__name time-message__name--sub">Мастер класс на льду</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--darkpink timeLeft timeLeft__15min timeWidth timeWidth__15min">
      <div class="time-message__info">
        <p class="time-message__duration time-message__duration--sub">11.45 - 12.00</p>
        <p class="time-message__name time-message__name--sub">Возвра-щение</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="js-open time-message__open-close">Развернуть подсобытия</div>
</div>
<div data-rubric="2" class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--blue timeLeft timeLeft__360min timeWidth">
  <div class="time-message__info">
    <p class="time-message__duration">09.00 - 10.00</p>
    <p class="time-message__name">Математика и геометрия</p>
    <p class="time-message__description">Смена "Смена кубок", группа Б.</p>
    <p class="time-message__location">(ауд.Менделеева)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Какие блоки надо вывести? Поподробнее пожалуйста

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade обновил вопрос, добавил блоки. Нужно что бы при выборе определенной рубрики, остальные скрывались. <br> Например при выборе рубрики "Общие события" показывались только события имеющие data-rubric="1"

Comment: Советую использовать Isotope. Очень стильно и современно. http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade, очень стильно и современно давать ссылки сразу на Гитхаб: https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope. А по поводу изотопа, пришли вы в магазин купить хлеба, а вам говорят, зачем вам хлеб, купите сразу сэндвич, это вкусно и питательно. Но ведь вам же всё равно нужен хлеб?

Comment: MasterAlex я вижу Вы у нас стиляга) Всем все подавай на блюдце. Да и аналогия просто ужасная) Вместо того, чтобы разводить оффтоп - лучше бы помогли парню с его задачей. Я поделился мнением, так как считаю правильным использовать наиболее современные подходы. Мое дело не сделать замечание, а помочь.

Comment: @Urmuz Tagizade, я высказался по поводу плагина, который вы предлагаете к использованию, а современный подход гласит, если функционал рациональнее сделать без использования сторонних плагинов, то лучше их не использовать. В данном случае не нужны никакие плагины. А помочь я не против, просто пока нет возможности посидеть над кодом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такой скрипт получился у меня для нужного функционала:

```js
var blocks = $('[data-rubric]');
var checkbox_items = $('.filter-rubric__item :checkbox');
 
$('body').on('click', '.filter-rubric__item :checkbox', function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    if($('.filter-rubric__item :checkbox:checked').length == 1){
       if($(this).prop('checked')) {
           blocks.hide();
           $('[data-rubric='+ name +']').show();
       } else {
           $('[data-rubric='+ name +']').hide();
       }
    } else if($('.filter-rubric__item :checkbox:checked').length > 1) {
      if($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('[data-rubric='+ name +']').show();
      } else {
        $('[data-rubric='+ name +']').hide();
      }
    } else {
      blocks.show();
    }
  });
```

```css
.filter-rubric__list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 12px;
}
.filter-rubric__label span {
  display: none;
}
.filter-rubric input {
  display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}
.filter-rubric__label {
  color: #979797;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  padding: 9px 0 14px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.filter-rubric__item:first-child .filter-rubric__label {
  padding: 3px 0 14px 0;
}
filter-rubric__label:before {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 9px;
  width: 16px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .filter-rubric__label span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1px;
  top: 10px;
}
.filter-rubric__label span > svg {
  height: 15px;
  width: 16px;
  fill: #ff5711;
}
svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.timeWidth {
  width: 178px;
}
.time-message__event-info--purple {
  background-color: #eee5f4;
}
.time-message__event-info {
  min-height: 101px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
.timeWidth {
  width: 178px;
}
.timeLeft__360min {
  left: 360px;
}
.timeLeft {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
.time-message__event-info--blue {
  background-color: #a9dcf6;
}
.time-message__event-info {
  min-height: 101px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
.time-message__event-info--pink {
  background-color: #fed5d5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-menu filter-rubric">
  <ul class="filter-rubric__list">
    <li class="filter-rubric__item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="1" id="rubric-1">
      <label for="rubric-1" class="filter-rubric__label">Наука<span><!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 16 15" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16 15;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<path d="M4.4,7l2.2,4c0,0,3.5-8.2,9.1-11C15.6,2,15,3.7,16,5.7c-2.4,0.5-7.5,6.4-9.1,9.3c-2.3-2.7-5-4.8-6.9-5.5L4.4,7z
 "></path>
</svg>
</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="filter-rubric__item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="2" id="rubric-2">
      <label for="rubric-2" class="filter-rubric__label">Спорт<span><!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 16 15" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16 15;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<path d="M4.4,7l2.2,4c0,0,3.5-8.2,9.1-11C15.6,2,15,3.7,16,5.7c-2.4,0.5-7.5,6.4-9.1,9.3c-2.3-2.7-5-4.8-6.9-5.5L4.4,7z
 "></path>
</svg>
</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="filter-rubric__item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="3" id="rubric-3">
      <label for="rubric-3" class="filter-rubric__label">Искусство<span><!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 16 15" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16 15;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<path d="M4.4,7l2.2,4c0,0,3.5-8.2,9.1-11C15.6,2,15,3.7,16,5.7c-2.4,0.5-7.5,6.4-9.1,9.3c-2.3-2.7-5-4.8-6.9-5.5L4.4,7z
 "></path>
</svg>
</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="filter-rubric__item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="4" id="rubric-4">
      <label for="rubric-4" class="filter-rubric__label">Общие события<span><!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 16 15" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16 15;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<path d="M4.4,7l2.2,4c0,0,3.5-8.2,9.1-11C15.6,2,15,3.7,16,5.7c-2.4,0.5-7.5,6.4-9.1,9.3c-2.3-2.7-5-4.8-6.9-5.5L4.4,7z
 "></path>
</svg>
</span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div data-rubric="1" class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--purple timeWidth">
  <div class="time-message__info">
    <p class="time-message__duration">07.00 - 08.00</p>
    <p class="time-message__name">Подъём и зарядка</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-rubric="2" class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--blue timeLeft timeLeft__360min timeWidth">
  <div class="time-message__info">
    <p class="time-message__duration">09.00 - 10.00</p>
    <p class="time-message__name">Математика и геометрия</p>
    <p class="time-message__description">Смена "Смена кубок", группа А.</p>
    <p class="time-message__location">(ауд.Менделеева)</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-rubric="3" class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--pink timeLeft timeLeft__360min timeWidth timeWidth__180min">
  <div class="time-message__info">
    <p class="time-message__duration">09.00 - 12.00</p>
    <p class="time-message__name">Мастер-класс Павла Бурре</p>
    <p class="time-message__description">Смена "Спортивной надежды сборной",</p>
    <p class="time-message__location">(стадион "Шайба")</p>
  </div>
  <div class="js-close-subevent time-message__event-in" style="display: none;">
    <div class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--darkpink timeWidth timeWidth__30min">
      <div class="time-message__info">
        <p class="time-message__duration time-message__duration--sub">09.00 - 09.30</p>
        <p class="time-message__name time-message__name--sub">Сбор - выход</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--darkpink timeLeft timeLeft__30min-sub timeWidth timeWidth__90min">
      <div class="time-message__info">
        <p class="time-message__duration time-message__duration--sub">10.00 -11.30</p>
        <p class="time-message__name time-message__name--sub">Мастер класс на льду</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--darkpink timeLeft timeLeft__15min timeWidth timeWidth__15min">
      <div class="time-message__info">
        <p class="time-message__duration time-message__duration--sub">11.45 - 12.00</p>
        <p class="time-message__name time-message__name--sub">Возвра-щение</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="js-open time-message__open-close">Развернуть подсобытия</div>
</div>
<div data-rubric="2" class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--blue timeLeft timeLeft__360min timeWidth">
  <div class="time-message__info">
    <p class="time-message__duration">09.00 - 10.00</p>
    <p class="time-message__name">Математика и геометрия</p>
    <p class="time-message__description">Смена "Смена кубок", группа Б.</p>
    <p class="time-message__location">(ауд.Менделеева)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "общие события" и показ data-rubric="1"  не совпадают.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, а может зарядка это "наука" :) но не суть, главное что скрипт работает как надо, а контента, который будет обрабатывать скрипт, думаю будет в любом случае больше

Comment: да я так.. но чувствую будет поросячий визг.

Comment: @MasterAlex а почему сделали через $('body').on('click', '.filter-rubric__item :checkbox', function() почему не работает через change?

Comment: @drtvader, ага, я тоже об этом подумал, но исправлять уже не стал, потому что и такой вариант имеет право на жизнь. Почему `change` не работает? вроде работает и, наверное, правильнее будет использовать всё-таки функцию 'change', которая будет отслеживать состояние чекбокса :)

Comment: @MasterAlex да, работает)

Answer (score 2):

Пардоньте за гомосяцкий подход. У автора вопроса не совпадает `name` значение инпута с `data-` блоком зарядки, подправил. Или я не понимаю как это относится к общим событиям.

```js
$(function() {
  $(':checkbox').on('change', function() {

    $(':checkbox').each(function(index, el) {
      var val = parseInt(($(this).attr('name')));

      if ($(el).prop('checked')) {
        $('.time-message__event-info').filter('div[data-rubric=' + val + ']').show();
      } else {
        $('.time-message__event-info').filter('div[data-rubric=' + val + ']').hide();
      }
    });

    if ($('.filter-rubric__item :checkbox:checked').length == 0) {
      $('.time-message__event-info').show('fast');
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.filter-rubric__list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 12px;
}
.filter-rubric__label span {
  display: none;
}
.filter-rubric input {
  display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}
.filter-rubric__label {
  color: #979797;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  padding: 9px 0 14px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.filter-rubric__item:first-child .filter-rubric__label {
  padding: 3px 0 14px 0;
}
.filter-rubric__label:before {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 9px;
  width: 16px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .filter-rubric__label span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1px;
  top: 10px;
}
.filter-rubric__label span > svg {
  height: 15px;
  width: 16px;
  fill: #ff5711;
}
svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.timeWidth {
  width: 178px;
}
.time-message__event-info--purple {
  background-color: #eee5f4;
}
.time-message__event-info {
  min-height: 101px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
.timeWidth {
  width: 178px;
}
.timeLeft__360min {
  left: 360px;
}
.timeLeft {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
.time-message__event-info--blue {
  background-color: #a9dcf6;
}
.time-message__event-info {
  min-height: 101px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
.time-message__event-info--pink {
  background-color: #fed5d5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-menu filter-rubric">
  <ul class="filter-rubric__list">
    <li class="filter-rubric__item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="100" id="rubric-100">
      <label for="rubric-100" class="filter-rubric__label">Наука<span><!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
     <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
     <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 16 15" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16 15;" xml:space="preserve">
      <style type="text/css">
      </style>
      <path d="M4.4,7l2.2,4c0,0,3.5-8.2,9.1-11C15.6,2,15,3.7,16,5.7c-2.4,0.5-7.5,6.4-9.1,9.3c-2.3-2.7-5-4.8-6.9-5.5L4.4,7z
      "></path>
     </svg>
    </span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="filter-rubric__item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="2" id="rubric-2">
      <label for="rubric-2" class="filter-rubric__label">Спорт<span><!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 16 15" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16 15;" xml:space="preserve">
     <style type="text/css">
     </style>
     <path d="M4.4,7l2.2,4c0,0,3.5-8.2,9.1-11C15.6,2,15,3.7,16,5.7c-2.4,0.5-7.5,6.4-9.1,9.3c-2.3-2.7-5-4.8-6.9-5.5L4.4,7z
     "></path>
    </svg>
   </span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="filter-rubric__item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="3" id="rubric-3">
      <label for="rubric-3" class="filter-rubric__label">Искусство<span><!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
   <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
   <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 16 15" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16 15;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
    <path d="M4.4,7l2.2,4c0,0,3.5-8.2,9.1-11C15.6,2,15,3.7,16,5.7c-2.4,0.5-7.5,6.4-9.1,9.3c-2.3-2.7-5-4.8-6.9-5.5L4.4,7z
    "></path>
   </svg>
  </span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="filter-rubric__item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="1" id="rubric-1">
      <label for="rubric-1" class="filter-rubric__label">Общие события<span><!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
  <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 16 15" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16 15;" xml:space="preserve">
   <style type="text/css">
   </style>
   <path d="M4.4,7l2.2,4c0,0,3.5-8.2,9.1-11C15.6,2,15,3.7,16,5.7c-2.4,0.5-7.5,6.4-9.1,9.3c-2.3-2.7-5-4.8-6.9-5.5L4.4,7z
   "></path>
  </svg>
 </span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div data-rubric="1" class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--purple timeWidth">
  <div class="time-message__info">
    <p class="time-message__duration">07.00 - 08.00</p>
    <p class="time-message__name">Подъём и зарядка</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-rubric="2" class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--blue timeLeft timeLeft__360min timeWidth">
  <div class="time-message__info">
    <p class="time-message__duration">09.00 - 10.00</p>
    <p class="time-message__name">Математика и геометрия</p>
    <p class="time-message__description">Смена "Смена кубок", группа А.</p>
    <p class="time-message__location">(ауд.Менделеева)</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-rubric="3" class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--pink timeLeft timeLeft__360min timeWidth timeWidth__180min">
  <div class="time-message__info">
    <p class="time-message__duration">09.00 - 12.00</p>
    <p class="time-message__name">Мастер-класс Павла Бурре</p>
    <p class="time-message__description">Смена "Спортивной надежды сборной",</p>
    <p class="time-message__location">(стадион "Шайба")</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-rubric="2" class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--blue timeLeft timeLeft__360min timeWidth">
  <div class="time-message__info">
    <p class="time-message__duration">09.00 - 10.00</p>
    <p class="time-message__name">Математика и геометрия</p>
    <p class="time-message__description">Смена "Смена кубок", группа Б.</p>
    <p class="time-message__location">(ауд.Менделеева)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно вас понял тогда можно как-то так

```
$('.filter-rubric__item input').change(function() {
  var ids = $(this).attr('name');
  var blocks = $('hidden__block');
  blocks.hide();
  var block = $('[data-rubric=' + ids +']');
  block.show();
});
```

Для блоков сначало прописываете стили что-бы они не отображались.
html

```
<div class="hidden__block" id="b1">...</div>
<div class="hidden__block" id="b2">...</div>
...
<div class="hidden__block" id="b...">...</div>
```

css

```
.hidden__block{ display: none;}
```

Comment: нет. изначально все блоки видны, а когда делаешь выбор, то все, не относящиеся к рубрике блоки скрываются. И если снять change, то все снова отображаются.

Comment: @Alexandr Trubachov, а почему бы ваш код не вживить в код автора вопроса, ведь это проще чем давать абстрактный код, который к тому же нельзя посмотреть и понажимать.

Comment: А что происходит если выбрано несколько чекбоксов?

Comment: @MasterAlex - можно и так, но тогда автору не будет смысла разбираться с тем как это работает, он просто скопирует и все.

Comment: @AlexandrTrubachov если выбрано несколько чекбоксов то отображаются соответствующие им блоки.

Comment: @AlexandrTrubachov как правильно написать селектор для тех блоков, которые нужно скрыть?